# how can we calculate width of any text

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a text in a div. I can output the width of the div as below

```
alert($("div").width());
```

But I am interested in getting the width of the text inside it excluding the border or padding space. If I specify the `font-family` as arial or verdana then the space occupied by text will be different. So I want to know how is the width of just text.

Thanks

Comment: tried to set margin and padding to 0 and setting `display: inline`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I set a span element around text and got exactly what I wanted.

Here is the code -

http://jsbin.com/oduvan/edit#javascript,html

Answer (score 1):

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/nawazhi/2DhJW/)**

Use `innerWidth()` and subtract Padding

```
 alert($("div").innerWidth()-($("div").css("padding").replace("px","")*2));
```

Answer (score 1):

```
    <div id="div">Some text here</div>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function(){
        var div2 = $('#div').clone();
        div2.addClass('for-calc');
        $('body').append(div2);
        $('.for-calc').html('<span style="display:inline; padding:0">' + $('.for-calc').html() + '</span>');
        var width = $('.for-calc > span').width();
        $('.for-calc').remove();
        alert(width);
    });
</script>
```

Variable **width** contains width of text from div#div